# Prove: $f$ can be extended over normal space $X$

Tags: general-topology

That is one of my topology exercises.

I want to prove that :

if $A$ is a close subset of normal space $X$,$f: A \to (-1,1)$ which is continuous, then $f$ can be extended to $\tilde{f} : X \to (-1,1)$.

If $f$ maps to $[-1,1]$, then that is trivial (since you can just use Tietze Extension Theorem), but when i tried to use the same method to work on this problem, i got stuck, because i can't use Urysohn's Lemma to construct a continuous function series.

So any hint would be helpful to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tietze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) holds with the codomain $\Bbb R$ and so also with the homeomorphic $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So $f$ is extendable on every interval of $\mathbb{R}$ because it's homeomorphic ? I think i didn't understand it in class.

Comment: @robothead not every interval is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, all open intervals and open segments are. But Tietze is true for all types of intervals in $\Bbb R$,  and in fact any contractible metric space.

Comment: I think that helps a lot! Thanks again!